# Symfony2 is not logging exceptions thrown inside custom command

Tags: logging, symfony, exception, symfony-2.1, monolog

When an error occurs during a normal http request, Symfony2 logs everything (depending on your logging level) and you can see it in dev.log or app.log.

But when you get an error during the execution of a custom command, it doesn't log anything. It just shows a red message in standard output, that doesn't even have a backtrace.

What can I do to have all errors logged, like in the first case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do this on my own, Symfony2 won't do it.

Create a BaseCommand to extend that catches all errors and exceptions and logs them.

Answer (score 2):

When you add `--verbose` option when run the command you should see backtrace.

I imagine that you can just catch `\Exception` and use monolog logger from the container (command have access to DIC) if you want.

I think you can do it in other way too if its needed for example by
extending `Symfony\Component\Console\Application` class and method `renderException` and log errors there but I never do that really, just see that Command/Application API should allow for that.